# Fedora: Adding extra fonts in a safe manner

Tags: fedora, fonts

I installed few free fonts from [smashingmagazine.com](http://www.smashingmagazine.com) on my Fedora 14 laptop. I didn't like them much so I removed them from `/usr/share/fonts` using `rm -f`. The consequence was that my Google Chrome browser fonts changed automatically.

Since Fedora 15 is around the corner, I don't care much about the issue. But after installing Fedora 15, I'd like to make sure that I can add and remove fonts safely from my laptop without affecting font settings in any other application (specially browser). How can I do that and what points should I keep in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing fonts under `$HOME/.fonts` directory is safer. `gnome-font-viewer` has a nifty install button which does exactly that.

If you want to install fonts system-wise, and in general before executing a `rm` command inside a system directory, check if the file to be deleted is owned by some rpm package

```
# rpm -qi --whatprovides /path/to/font.ttf
```